# Website Not Cached by Google Since 1 and Half Months

Tags: google, cache

My website `www.rushinformation.com` is not being cached by Google since 1 April 2013 but pages are getting indexed. My robots.txt file is fine. So please tell me what could be the reason for this and how should I fix this issue? Does it affect my website rankings in the future???

Answer (score 1):

**Using site:www.yoursite.com**

I can tell that you have many cached by using site:www.yoursite.com

for example:

1. [30th April](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZYi0-Ji8OrsJ%3awww.rushinformation.com/encrypt-offline-files-in-windows-7-fixed/%20&cd=163&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)
2. [1st April](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3asbrO7r713JYJ%3awww.rushinformation.com/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)
3. [23 March](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7muZITyQb74J%3awww.rushinformation.com/disclaimer/%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)
4. [22nd Feb](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aAumh9SuL9dAJ%3awww.rushinformation.com/tag/android/%20&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a)

**Above examples**

As you can see from the above examples that your pages are caching just fine, Google search results and caching services work independently and has no effect on your rankings. The more you update your site and the more trust you gain with Google the more often you get crawls which will speed up indexing and caching time, its also worth mentioning that the caching service is not real time as those of indexed pages, its common to see pages that are indexed days, weeks to months before they are cached. Gaining more site authority gives your site more priority over others which will speed up the process as mentioned before.

Nothing to worry about.